# Ubuntu 23.04 - Rectangles instead of text on SPAs

Tags: fonts, 23.04

While using some SPAs (tested with Teams for Linux and Whatsie), every time I open the Files app through the app itself (to download/upload files), it shows squares instead of the actual text.

[image]

I already tried to execute a command suggested from a previous question, but didn't help

```
apt-get install --reinstall ttf-ubuntu-font-family 

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Package ttf-ubuntu-font-family is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'ttf-ubuntu-font-family' has no installation candidate
```

Comment: You're definitely missing a font. The issue is finding out what it is. I had a similar problem with `aptik` a while back; it was missing `fonts-liberation2`. No idea if that is what your app is missing though.

Answer (score 0):

This seems related to the `23.04` version of Ubuntu.
All looking good after upgrading to `23.10`.